# How to make a sticky sidebar stay inside the screen?

Tags: jquery, css

I got a sticky sidebar minicart and I realized after I add lots of data (products to cart) it goes below the screen as in outside of the screen. How do you prevent it from going outside of the screen?

Maybe making it responsive?

This is the jQuery we are using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop(),
    sidebar = $('.x-sidebar');

if (scrollPos > 200) {
   sidebar.addClass('fixed-sidebar');
 } else {
   sidebar.removeClass('fixed-sidebar');
  }
 });
});
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: Try giving the element a `max-height: 100vh`

Comment: this should help, particularly fixed : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: .fixed-sidebar {max-height: 100vh; overflow-y: auto;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to set the position fixed to element and set the margin to content element.

I don't know what is your layout to have a idea what is happening there.

```css
html, body
{
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar
{
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: fixed;
  background: green;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 200px;
  top: 0;
}

.content
{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
  <p>6</p>
  <p>7</p>
  <p>8</p>
  <p>9</p>
  <p>+</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
  <p>6</p>
  <p>7</p>
  <p>8</p>
  <p>9</p>
  <p>+</p>
</div>
```

More: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_sidebar.asp